# Passing Data of Page 1 to Page 3 in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I pass the data of home(page 1) to ContactPage(page 3) along with DetailsPage(page 2) data?

lets say

HomePage has data of "UserId"

DetailsPage has data of "UserName" & "UserAddress" //this page doesnt have UserID

now how can i get the data of 
"UserId" as well as "UserName & UserAddress" on ContactPage?

Comment: userid is unique so you can store it somewhere like local storage, service etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in HomePage pass data as follow

```
this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage, {
      UserId: 'UserId'
    });
```

**in about page**

--retrieve value using

```
this.UserId = navParams.get('UserId');
```

--and send data from DetailsPage to ContactPage as

```
this.navController.push(ContactPage, {
    UserId: this.UserId, UserName: 'UserName', UserAddress: 'UserAddress'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow several ways

From your home page store userId in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('userId',<your variable>)
```

then from your second page if it is not a root page

```
    this.navCtrl.push('ContactPage',{
    userName:<your variable>,
    userAddress:<your variable>
})
```

then from your third page
fetch userId from `localStorage` like `localStorage.getItem('userId')` and the userName and userAddress using `NavParams`

```
this.navParams.get('userName'),
this.navParams.get('userAddress '),
```

let me know your outcome

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link to pass data from one page to another page

[Passing-data-between-pages-in-an-ionic-application](http://%20https://hackernoon.com/passing-data-between-pages-in-an-ionic-application-129b387c93b8)